# Just installed SASS, but can't get its version

Tags: terminal, sass, rubygems, version, homebrew

I installed SASS from the terminal, just `gem install sass`. And I see it says "Successfully installed sass-3.2.9."

However, when I then do `sass --version` or `sass --v` I get this error:

-bash: sass: command not found

[image]

The only thing I can think of is, when I was doing the Git tutorials on Tuts+ I ran into a local vs. global issue or I had to edit a bash_profile file.

This is what is inside the bash_profile file inside my user directory:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

Any thoughts or tips on why I can't get the version of SASS or Compass I just installed? (I can only get `ruby --version`.)

Comment: Note: I just tried sudo gem install sass, which installed sass a 3rd time now, but I still get that 'bash' error when I type sass --v

Comment: Try auto completing the `sass` command.  All of my Ruby programs have a `19` postfix to signify Ruby 1.9 (ie. `sass19` or `compass19`).  You could also try resetting your terminal.

Comment: like sass19 --version? Tried that, but it didn't work :( may look into resetting, but I did have to create a bash_profile to install git correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got the answer!
https://superuser.com/questions/600262/error-when-installing-and-trying-to-get-version-of-sass-via-terminal?noredirect=1#comment739892_600262

```
$ brew --prefix ruby
/usr/local/opt/ruby
$ stat -f%Y /usr/local/opt/ruby
../Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p0
$ export PATH=/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH
$ which sass
/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/sass
```