# -bash: sass: command not found after git import

Tags: git, sass

I recently cloned a `git` project and wanted to watch the `themes` folder, under which it has been installed. i can see my .`sass-cache` and `styles.scss` but when i install it, it tells me, `-bash: sass: command not found` . I have googled it but nothing as much. I am running mac

Comment: @Vandesh mac comes pre-installed with mac

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Just installed SASS, but can't get it's version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16760776/just-installed-sass-but-cant-get-its-version)